# How to run custom update query on JpaRepository?(TransactionRequiredException)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to write 2 native SQL queries in spring,

My query annotation with SQL in service class is:

```
    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *")
    void testMethod() {

    String query = "UPDATE BUDGET_GROUP_SPEND_SUMMARY BSS, USER U, EMPLOYEE_MOVE_STAGE EMS, BUDGET B, SERVICE_GROUP SG " +
                "SET BSS.BULK_RECALC_LOCK = true " +
                "WHERE BSS.EMPLOYEE_ID = U.USER_ID " +
                "AND U.USER_ID = EMS.USER_ID " +
                "AND BSS.BUDGET_GROUP_ID = B.BUDGET_ID " +
                "AND B.BUDGET_SERVICE_GROUP_ID IS NOT NULL " +
                "AND EMS.MOVE_STAGE_ID IN (1,2) " +
                "AND U.USER_CUSTOMER_STATUS IN ('MOVE_COMPLETED', 'LOST', 'GET_FEEDBACK', 'CLOSED_NO_FEEDBACK', 'ON_ASSIGNMENT') " +
                "AND B.BUDGET_SERVICE_GROUP_ID = SG.SERVICE_GROUP_ID " +
                "AND SG.MOVE_STAGE_ID = 1";

        Query nq = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);

        nq.executeUpdate();
    }
```

But I received this error:

```
2019-09-12 18:28:00,012 ERROR [] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

If I use `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();` and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();`

then its throwing :

> 2019-09-12 18:36:00,007 ERROR []
>   o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95 - Unexpected error occurred
>   in scheduled task. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to
>   create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions
>   or EJB CMT instead
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManager

Why do I get this error?

Or is there any other better way to implement custom update query with `Jpa Repository`?

Comment: Could you share persistence.xml? Check what is configured on transaction-type

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume *Spring* **will not create a transaction proxy** since your method is not `public`.
2. You should always try to **avoid manual transaction management** if you are using declarative *Spring Transaction Manager*
3. Your application should have a **separate layer that handles DB calls**. In your case, it's JPA repositories. So it's better to implement a query in a custom Jpa repository, inject its instance here and invoke appropriate method.